# Mule Parameterized query not showing in logs

Tags: mule, mule-studio

log4j2.xml has AsyncLogger name="org.mule.module.db" level="INFO" but i am not seeing the parameterized query in the logs. I have log4j2.xml under /src/main/resources. I am using parameterized query to perform update operation on sql server. I would like to see the queries which are constructed during runtime in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

In order to log the SQL statement being executed by Mule, you need to add the following log4j configuration.

For the new DB module:

log4j.logger.org.mule.module.db=DEBUG

For the old JDBC transport:

log4j.logger.com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc=DEBUG

see https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/ka4340000004GWgAAM/Logging-the-SQL-statements-in-Mule
See https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7371

Comment: I am using log4j2.xml and already has AsyncLogger name="org.mule.module.db" level="INFO"  in the log4j2.xml. log4j.logger.org.mule.module.db=DEBUG is for log4j.xml.

Comment: Have you tried setting AsyncLogger name="org.mule.module.db" level="DEBUG"

Secondly have checked the class path to see which  log4j2.xml is being picked up, I found this blog useful interms of child first pattern http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/mule-3-6-asynchronous-logging/

Comment: Also search google for ""-M-Dlog4j.debug=true"  and you will find help how to track which log4j2 is being picked up so you can be sure your changes are being respected at runtime